# Vanilla julia 1.6.4 installation: Failed to precompile Plots

Tags: package, julia, plots.jl

Vanilla julia-1.6.4 installation.
Ubuntu 20 LTS

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the input and output instead of including an image. Images are (i) hard to read and (ii) unsearchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a [broken release](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/3964) by the package maintainers and it has now been [revoked](https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General/pull/49708). You can add the previous version explicitly, which hopefully works:

```
pkg> add Plots@1.24.3
```